# Handling SIGABRT in Mac Apps

Tags: macos, sigabrt, .app

I have created a very simple Desktop app for Mac OS.  Due to restrictions, I could not use xcode.  I am building the .app directory by hand, and the main executable at the moment is a shell script.

When I was trying my app out, I noticed that if I opened and closed it too quickly, the app would freeze up.  At which point, I seemed unable to even force quit it, and had to rm -r the .app itself.  A friend mentioned to me, that mac apps must handle SIGABRTs, and if they do not, there is a timeout period where the app could appear as frozen, which might explain what I observed.

I was looking around but uncertain where to find more information about this.  Can anyone further explain this situation?  Under what circumstances will the app receive a SIGABRT, and how should it be handled?  Any links or literature on this topic, would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone ever stumbles upon this:

So my friend was referring to Unix signals here.  https://people.cs.pitt.edu/~alanjawi/cs449/code/shell/UnixSignals.htm

(to see what is available on your OS, give 'kill -l')

My main executable, in my MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS, is a shell script.  So what I've found I can do, is use trap command.  This will give a behavior to perform, if the executable receives one of the signals.  Example - I now add this line near the top of my shell script:

trap 'exit' 5 6

This means that if the executable receives with a SIGABRT (6) or a SIGTRAP (5) signal, it will perform the command 'exit' and will exit.  (I am not certain which all signals should be handled and what is the best course, I guess that might depend on your own app, but that was just as an example of something to do)

Here is a resource about trap commands and unix signals: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-signals-traps.htm

Why does this make a difference - I believe previously, there were scenarios where for example if I opened the app while it was already open, it was receiving a Unix signal like a SIGABRT.  This signal was not being handled and the app did not know what to do in that scenario, and was freezing up.  Though I have not confirmed this is what was happening.